# Equation in Field Quantization Greiner

Tags: conservation-laws, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

[image: Field Quantization Greiner]

Hello, I dont understand the red part. Shouldn't it have minus instead?
Sorry for lack of formatting, I only have a phone.

Answer (score 0):

$\chi_{\sigma \mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2}(\chi_{\sigma \mu \nu} + \chi_{\sigma \mu \nu}) = \frac{1}{2}(\chi_{\sigma \mu \nu} + \chi_{ \mu \sigma \nu}) = 0$

due to the anti-symmetry property of $\chi$, $\chi_{\sigma \mu \nu} = -\chi_{\mu \sigma \nu}$. The minus sign does not need to be where you think it should be since you can also write $\chi_{\mu \sigma \nu} = - \chi_{\sigma \mu \nu}$.

Remember that what you label subscripts/superscripts is arbitrary but you need to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The plus is good. That step is not really needed but all is doing is explicitly taking the symmetric part of the tensor (which is zero) since $\partial^\mu\partial^\sigma$ is itself symmetric. The antisymmetric part would have had a minus but being $\partial^\mu\partial^\sigma$ symmetric, the contraction with the antisymmetric part of $\chi_{\sigma\mu\nu}$ would have given zero.